# How do I create a relative link to a downloaded jquery library?

Tags: html, dynamic-linking

I am having trouble linking to a jquery library and am wondering if someone might be able to point out what I am doing wrong.

My html page is a locally hosted Sharepoint site here:

```
http://server/sites/blog/dude/Pages/MyPage.html
```

and my jquery library is located here:

```
http://server/sites/blog/style%20library/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

I it works fine if I reference the whole jquery address like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src='http://server/sites/blog/style%20library/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
```

But it isn't located when I do this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src='../../blog/style%20library/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
```

Am I using the "folder up" syntax incorrectly perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `/sites/blog/style%20library/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js`

The leading slash tells the browser to go to the host and start from there.

Comment: Would I be able to use a /../ instead of /sites/ as when I move the site that value probably will change.